# Getting total over trailing three week periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a large table of (say) users and their visits to various webpages.  An example of the table could be:

```
schema.page_views

      date|  user_id|         webpage|
----------+---------+----------------+
01/05/2012|aaaaaaaaa|www.example1.com|
01/06/2012|aaaaaaaaa|www.example2.com|
01/06/2012|ababababa|www.example1.com|
                     ...
01/05/2013|aaaaaaaaa|www.example2.com|
01/05/2013|ababababa|www.example1.com|
03/05/2013|aaaaaaaaa|www.example2.com|
```

Additionally, I have a calendar lookup table:

```
schema.weeks

week_number| begin_date|   end_date|year|
-----------+-----------+-----------+----+
         18| 2012-04-23| 2012-04-30|2012|
         17| 2012-04-15| 2012-04-22|2012|
         16| 2012-04-08| 2012-04-14|2012|
```

What I would ultimately like from these two tables is a trailing three week total of page views.  More specifically, if I was issuing this query today, I would like something along the lines of:

```
         webpage|    1-3|    4-6|    7-9|  10-12|   
----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
www.example1.com| 124875| 175682| 168542| 159780|
www.example2.com|    three week period numbers  |
```

where '1-3' refers to the most recent three weeks, '4-6' refers to four to six weeks ago, etc.

So far, I've obtained the weekly total page views for each website and week, as follows:

```
-- join to get begin and end_dates
with t1 as (
select a.*, b.* from schema.page_views a
join schema.weeks b
on a.date between b.begin_date and b.end_date),

-- now aggregate per week
weekly_vol as (
select webpage, year, week_number, begin_date, end_date,
count(*) volume
from t1
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

select * from weekly_vol limit 1;
```

gives, for example,

```
         webpage| year| week_number| begin_date|   end_date| volume|
----------------+-----+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
www.example1.com| 2012|          18| 2012-04-23| 2012-04-30|  41871|
```

With a table like this, how can I get to the table I would like?  I have thought of joining it on itself with something like `on a.week_number between b.week_number and b.week_number + 2` but I don't think this idea will work when the last twelve weeks include the start of a new year.

Has anyone done something similar, and if so, how did you approach the problem?  Suggestions for a different approach would be appreciated equally.

Comment: trailing 3 week sum per year or all years combined?

Comment: @vkp I'd really like four three week periods (as in the OP) for this current year, and last year, but if I knew how to do it for this year, I don't think it'd be much different to get last year, too.

Comment: the weeks table is irrelevant in that case as the results depend on the day you run it..is this assumption correct?

Comment: @vkp No, I think I definitely need the weeks table...  The day I run it dictates which weeks from the weeks table I limit to.

Comment: it would help if you can show some representative data and the expected output..also show the case how it should be handled at year ends..even better if you can setup a sqlfiddle.

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd not that you cant do this in sql, but is there some application that is reading this data? Maybe easier to deliver the data to the app and use the app to reformat to the desired output.

Comment: @DavidLee That is an approach that I've considered, but for my specific case doing it in one SQL query would be strongly preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear.  Are week numbers just within a year or over all time?  Do you want the sums relative to the last week in the data or relative to the current date?

In any case, the following does something that is at least similar to what you want.  The key is the conditional aggregation in the outer query:

```
with t1 as (
      select pv.*, w.*,
             max(pv.week_number) over (partition by webpage, year) as last_week_number
      from schema.page_views pv join
           schema.weeks w
           on pv.date between w.begin_date and w.end_date
     ),
     weekly_vol as (
      select webpage, year, week_number, begin_date, end_date,
             count(*) as volume
      from t1
      group by webpage, year, week_number, begin_date, end_date
    )
select webpage, year,
       sum(case when last_week_number - week_number < 3
                then volume else 0
           end) as week_1_3,
       sum(case when last_week_number - week_number >= 3 and  last_week_number - week_number < 6
               then volume else 0
           end) as week_4_6
from weekly_vol 
group by webpage, year;
```

Comment: `max(pv.week_number) over (partition by webpage, year)` will not take into account all the days/weeks a webpage is present in a year..so the calculation would be off in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity...  To answer your specific questions: The week numbers are just within one year (1-52 for each year).  This was implied (vaguely, I guess) with the last sentence in the second-to-last paragraph.  An example might help with the second question...

Comment: Given today's date, we are in week 19 (by looking at the weeks table).  I would simply like to count the total number of page views for each website in weeks 17, 18, and 19 (which would be the value in the '1-3' column in the desired result table), in weeks 14, 15, and 16 (populating the '4-6' column), and so forth.  The reason that I thought this would present difficulties when changing years is that, if it's January 5th, 2017 (for instance), I would like the totals from week 1 of 2017, and the totals from weeks 51 and 52 to populate the '1-3' column.